# How to configure an aws elb for a windows machine

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, ssl

I am currently running a windows machine on AWS which is available via http to run some reports in a database.
this is working fine, when accessing the ip or the public dns of that instance.

Since reports shall not be transported to the user via port 80, i want this machine to be accessible via https.

I did create a Loadbalancer and did a bind to the instance from that windows machine.

When i access the loadbalancer's Public DNS i get a "504 Gateway Time-out" which i read is a timeout of the instance that is not responding in time. I also increased the idle-timeout to 180seconds ( 60 is default ).

I did setup many loadbalancers for linux ( ubuntu ) - machines and that worked pretty straight forward - so i am wondering, what setup needs to be done to get that windows machine accessable via the loadbalancer's DNS.

The final vision is to have a readable name reports.domainname.com use CNAME with the loadbalancer's DNS running on https

Is there anything i can investigate more? ( i am not very familiar with windows machines - maybe i am missing out somewhere? )

Thanks!

Comment: Have you configured your EC2 instance's security group to allow traffic from its HTTPS port to the ELB? You should also check on Windows Firewall rules, as it can block traffic as well.

Comment: Hey, i am not even getting this far to access via https. Just calling the ELBs public DNS already leads to the 504 - Page, which is running on port 80.
ELB-security Port is open for Port 80, also the instance's Security Group is open for Port 80...